# RecyclerView ANR during fast fling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView (1.2.1), with a List adapter, and ViewHolder, backed by a Room PagingSource.  There's about 700 items on the list.  The paging seems to work fine, and I've flattened my View hierarchy as much as I can.

Upon initially loading the recycler view, everything seems fine. Paging works, everything seems snappy. `onCreateViewHolder` in my adapter is called 14 times, and initially 5 are visible on the screen.

Slower scrolling is fine (it does call `onCreateViewHolder` more often than I expected, but there's no jank).

The problem comes when rapidly flinging through the list.  After 3-5 fast flings, it appears to decide that it needs to have more cached view holders, and makes many, many calls to `onCreateViewHolder` - this method is clocking in at ~5ms, but there's just too many of them, and the scrolling stops.  It appears to call `onCreateViewHolder` ~700 times - the same as the number of items on the list, like it's not recycling the views at all.

At that point, sometimes the app will recover, and at that point everything is smooth and it doesn't appear to need to create more ViewHolders. Sometimes however I will get the ANR dialog.

I've tried tweaking the recyclerView.recycledViewPool.setMaxRecycledViews(), but this doesn't appear to to increase the recycledViewCount until *after* the mass `onCreateViewHolder` calls.

Is there anything I can do to resolve this? Make the fling speed slower? Tune the view holder recycling somehow so that it doesn't go nuts and try and create so many at once?

I don't think I can get the layout inflation any better, given my design and data constraints. And even if I could, it's still creating waaay too many to be able to get them done in under 16ms!

Comment: can it be that some internal logic of your *onCreateViewHolder* could be tuned up/more optimized?

Comment: I do: `MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(...))`

The MyViewHolder creation itself takes almost no time at all - all it does is about a dozen itemView.findViewById calls and look up a couple of colors - happens in a few microseconds. 

The vast bulk of the time comes from layout inflation.

Comment: e.g., 6059 microSeconds for view inflation, 42 microseconds for view holder creation.

Comment: binding takes .25-2ms, FWIW.

Comment: seems interesting, I would check the possibility to move some code to a background thread and see how it behaves, check the Executor, for example `protected Executor myExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();`

Comment: I cannot move view inflation to a background thread. The ViewHolder has to be passed a view.

Comment: override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false)
        )
    }

The call to:            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false) is what takes 6ms.

Comment: pls share the code, no description can show the real problem if there is no code shared.

Comment: Try to disable the over-scroll with `android:overScrollMode="never"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my situation, I needed to do 2 things. First and foremost, I needed to adjust my paging configuration. My `prefetchDistance` was too small in relation to my page size! This got rid of the ANR - no more mass creation of ViewHolders!

The recyclerView would still pause scrolling when loading a page (especially towards the end). I added a `loadStateFlow` collector that handles showing a loading indicator so that the user knows there's more data coming.